# psql: FATAL: database "db_name" is not currently accepting connections

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I have a rails app running on a Postgres 9.3.5 database. This has been up & running for some time on my development environment. Today I applied a rails migration, and then when I attempted to run a `rake db:reset`, I received the error:

```
 psql: FATAL: database "db_name" is not currently accepting connections
```

This is now the only response when I attempt to run any psql or rake db tasks. For example:

```
  $ psql -d db_name
  psql: FATAL:  database "db_name" is not currently accepting connections
```

I can see db_name in the list of dbs, and it has the correct owner.

What would cause the state of "not currently accepting connections", and how can it be fixed?

Answer (score 13):

That message is only emitted if `datallowconn` has been set to false in `pg_catalog.pg_database`. This is used to protect the `template0` database from accidental modification, but is otherwise not done by PostgreSQL its self.

It's hard to imagine how you got into that state on another database, unless you were manually `UPDATE`ing the system catalogs.

There's an undocumented option to `ALTER DATABASE`, `allow_connections = false`, which would produce the same result, but it seems even less likely that you'd do that.

If you somehow get into that situation on a database that isn't a reserved template, you can

```
UPDATE pg_database SET datallowconn = true WHERE datname = 'my_database';
```

Comment: ERROR:  column "datallowcon" of relation "pg_database" does not exist

Answer (score 3):

Manually removing the database with `dropdb` worked:

```
$ dropdb 'db_name'
```

Then I was able to use `db:setup` to seed a fresh database.